# Getting problem to wall post on Facebook

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I login to Facebook through my app, everything works, but I'm having problems posting to walls.

```
- (NSString *) postToFBWallStatus:(NSString *) status andSetDelegate: (id) delegate
{
    if (! isFBLoggedIn) 
    {
        return @"NotLoggedin";
    }

    NSString *message = status;
    NSLog(@"Appdelegate: postToFBWallStatus:andSetDelegate:");
    NSLog(@"to be delegate class: %@",[delegate class]);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

    ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [newRequest setPostValue:message forKey:@"message"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"name"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"caption"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"description"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"link"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"picture"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:_accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
    [newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(postToWallFinished:)];
    [newRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(postToWallFailed:)];
    [newRequest setDelegate:delegate];
    [newRequest startAsynchronous];

    return @"Loggedin";
}
```

I get this message when I post to the Facebook wall:

```
error =     {
        message = "Invalid access token signature.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
```

Comment: I've had the same problem. The problem was that my database was truncating the access token because I had the column that stores it set as a VARCHAR(100).  As it turns out, 100 characters isn't enough for some access tokens, so the access token that was being sent was invalid.

Comment: How are you obtaining the value for the access token?

Comment: You're going to need to register with Facebook to get an Oauth key and then the user needs to approve the application before it will work.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the Facebook SDK for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the user's `access_token` to post information to their wall. Furthermore, the user needs to allow the `publish_stream` permission for the API call to work. When you authenticate the user, add `publish_stream` to the scope of permissions.